# Google contacts addition via Apps Script not working as expected

Tags: google-apps-script, google-contacts-api

I am trying the very first piece of google apps script code to create a new contact. The goal is to automatically create the contacts from a google sheet in future and store in the "Contacts" so that all get synched to my phone. However, the created contacts are getting created under "Other Contacts" and not "Contacts". The contacts available under "Other Contacts" do not get synced to the phone automatically. Where is the mistake I am doing?

I have tried the simple code to add a contact in google apps script. (Referred from the documentation)

```
function CreateContact() {
  var contact = ContactsApp.createContact('Rahul', 'Kumar', 'rahul.kumar@gmail.com');
}
```

Expected output : Contact getting created under "Contacts"

Actual output : Contact getting created under "Other Contacts"

Answer (score 0):

## Add New Contacts to a Label

I found that if you add them to a label then they get added to your contacts quickly. So here's a function that does just that.

```
function addContact(first,last,email,label) {
  var label=label || 'New';//default label
  if(first && last && email && label) {
    var contact=ContactsApp.createContact(first,last,email);
    var allgroups=ContactsApp.getContactGroups();//gets all groups
    var grpnames=getGroupNamesArray();//Get all the names of your groups in an array
    var index=grpnames.indexOf(label);
    if(index==-1) {
      var grp=ContactsApp.createContactGroup(label);
    }else{
      var grp=allgroups[index];//if group is already there then use it
    }
    contact.addToGroup(grp);  
  }
  //var html=Utilities.formatString('<br />Add New Contact<br />First: %s, Last: %s Email: %s', contact.getGivenName(),contact.getFamilyName(),contact.getEmails()[0].getAddress());//debugging
  //var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);//debugging
  //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'Contact');/debugging
}

function getGroupNamesArray() {
  var allGrps=ContactsApp.getContactGroups();
  var allNames=[];
  for(var i=0;i<allGrps.length;i++) {
    allNames.push(allGrps[i].getName());
  }
  return allNames;
}
```

You can add contacts like this:

function testAddContact1() {
  addContact('Kenny','Corral','kenny@missyou.com',null);//null with take the default value.  Which you can change to anything you want.
}

- [ContactApp Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/contacts-app)

Answer (score 0):

We need to add it to the my contacts group
var mainGroup = ContactsApp.getContactGroup("System Group: My Contacts");